# multiple associations between two models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm trying to associate two models in two ways in a Rails 3 app. People have many pets and each person can have one favorite pet.

Am I using the correct associations and foreign keys?

I actually get two different numbers when I do person.favorite_pet_id and person.favorite_pet.id

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets # pets table has a person_id
  has_one :favorite_pet, :class_name => 'Pet' # persons table has favorite_pet_id 
end


class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person # using person_id in pets table
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it looks like you have the favorite_pet_id in the persons table (as you should) you need to use the "belongs_to" association instead of "has_one", like so:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets # pets table has a person_id
  belongs_to :favorite_pet, :class_name => 'Pet' # persons table has favorite_pet_id 
end


class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person # using person_id in pets table
end
```

This should fix your issue.  I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate you answering my sorta stupid question. This worked. I overlooked "belongs to" because it doesn't seem to describe the relationship, but I see now how it does in the context of Rails.

Comment: I agree, "belongs_to" doesn't always fit the real world perfectly. It works 99% percent of the time.  Maybe in the case of pets, it helps to remember who's cleaning up after whom :)